# React re-render component on click

Tags: reactjs, onclick, rerender

i have function **addComment** that will make put request to the server and add comment to specific post

```
  const addComment = async (e) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/comment`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: user._id,
          body: comment.current.value,
          postId: postId.current.value,
        }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

the function will be triggered **onClick**

```
        <div className="doComment">
          <input
            className="commentInput"
            ref={comment}
            placeholder="Write a comment.."
          />
          <div className="addComment">
            <button onClick={addComment}>confirm</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I'm showing **comments** by mapping **comments** array that is coming from **post** prop through another component

```
        {post.comments.map((comment) => (
          <div className="comments" key={comment._id}>
            <div className="commentUserImageAndUsername">
              <img
                className="commentUserImg"
                src={
                  comment.userId === users._id
                    ? users.profileImg || `${PF}/profile.jpg`
                    : null
                }
                alt="comment user "
              />
              {comment.userId === users._id ? users.firstname : null}
            </div>

            <div className="commentBody">{comment.body}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

i want this component to re-render on **post.comments** prop change ( **onClick** after adding a comment ), so the user do not need to refresh the page to see the post comments, how to do that?

Comment: To re-render automatically you need to update the state of your component doing so  will trigger the render function.

Comment: How are you passing down the prop? if it's a state it will automatically re-render when set

Comment: yeah but what state, i don't have state for post or comments, **post** is actually a prop coming from another component

Comment: yes its a state, in that component it make request to get posts and set the posts using setState, then mapping posts and send every post as a prop